# Is jquery's load() safe for refreshing search results?

Tags: jquery, load

I'm asking myself if its safe to use jquery's load function for refreshing content on my page after selecting a new category, or searching for a term?

I'm coding a small inventory page with a Filter-section where you can choose from different categories, search for keyword and so on..

After selecting a new category Im loading the new content into the right place ("#listing") with the following function:

```
$("#load").on('click', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cat = $("#category").val();
    var tag = $("#tag").val();
    $("#listings").load("template/_listing.php?cat="+cat+"&tag="+tag);
});
```

The file in template/_listing.php echos out everything it found in HTML..

So everything works fine expect some styles and scripts which are not useable for the new loaded data (I think I just need to load the scripts also in the template/_listing.php file)..

Buuut I'm not really sure if this is the best way to do..
That way you can also access the adresse templates/_listing.php?cat=bla&tag=blu and I'm not sure if this is good?

I could also try it with an ajax call, fetch the JSON and "create" the search results inside my script.. would this be better?

I think it should be okay like I did it, if I make the "template/_listing.php" safe enough so that nobody can come into my database with other query then "cat or tag" or?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it's safe and this is one of good way for the purpose. But I recommend you to do it this way:

```
$("#listings").load(
"template/_listing.php?cat="+cat+"&tag="+tag,
function() {
    //put your js script here to fix those not useable
    //e.g. $("#listings .datepicker").datepicker();
});
```